# Access denied for user 'speedycm_root'@'localhost' to database 'speedycms'

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-error-1045

been trying to set up a webserver with uk2.net all day but i keep receiving the following error when i try to log in:

```
Access denied for user 'speedycm_root'@'localhost' to database 'speedycms'
```

what could it mean?

```
<?php
# FileName="Connection_php_mysql.htm"
# Type="MYSQL"
# HTTP="true"
$hostname_speedycms = "localhost";
$database_speedycms = "speedycm_database";
$username_speedycms = "speedycm_root";
```

// have omitted password but it is correct

```
$password_speedycms = "___________";

$speedycms = mysql_pconnect($hostname_speedycms, $username_speedycms, $password_speedycms) or trigger_error(mysql_error(),E_USER_ERROR); 
?>
```

i am using uk2.net hosting btw

Comment: Either you didn't supply a password or your login information is incorrect, only your hosting provider's support can help I think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means what it says, the named user is denied access to the named database.

Make sure the [user exists](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/adding-users.html) in the database, was [GRANT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/grant.html)ed access to the database and uses the correct password, if any. Could it be the username is `speedycms_root` (mind the s)?

If this won't help, go through [Causes of Access Denied Errors](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/access-denied.html)

Comment: it was a problem with the username thanks... apparently my host changed it