# PHP code will not connect to database

Tags: mysql

I can connect to MySQL server but not the DB. So on my webpage it shows "Connected to MySQL" but then underneath that I get "Could not select examples which tells me it didn't connect to the database". Could anyone help?

```
<?php
$username = "user_admin";
$password = "Password";
$hostname = "localhost:3306"; 

//connection to the database
$dbhandle = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) 
  or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");
echo "Connected to MySQL<br>";
?>

**<?php
//select a database to work with
$selected = mysql_select_db ("my_dbname", $dbhandle)
  or die("Could not select examples");  
?>**

<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `company` WHERE \'companyname\' like \'%a%\' LIMIT 0, 30 "; 

 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql))
   {
   echo $row['companyname'];
   echo "<br>";
   }

 mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: BTW what is it with the `\'companyname\'`

Comment: What it may *reall* be telling you is that the database `my_dbname` doesn't exist. Are you 10000% it does?

Comment: and you are sure you have that database ??

Comment: `mysql_` is deprecated. But use the command line to check permissions. i.e. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql.html

Comment: The companyname is a field within the company table. The database definitely exists, I have just double checked and it is holding within the company table over 849,000 rows.

Comment: you should not quote fieldnames (and as this one `companyname` doesn't contain any special characters should shouldn't even enclose it in (nonportable) backticks either)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Lincb said, maybe the database doesn't exist.

Try to display the error to have more information :

```
$selected = mysql_select_db('my_dbname', $dbhandle);
if (!$selected ) {
   die ('Error database : ' . mysql_error());
}
```

Comment: I have used your script Tosx. Error database : Access denied for user 'my_username'@'localhost' to database 'my_dbname'

Comment: I think the information like password is not correct.
Try to open directly your phpMyadmin or your database client, and access to your base.
Your password is 'Password' ? 
Generaly the default identifiant is : 
login : root
pwd : ""

Comment: This means you either have the wrong password, or you don't have permissions for that db. Can you try accessing it through PHPMyAdmin or some other way? If you can get into it there, then your script has the wrong password.

Comment: The password must be correct as there is only one used in the script. It connects to MYSQL but not to the DB, so if the password was incorrect surely it would fail on connecting to MYSQL too? I access MySQL through hostgator so I do not get prompted for any username or password and cannot see a logout option.

Comment: using 'hostgator' can you see your table ? Indeed is weird that the database connection don't failed.
Try to list all database using this :

$sql = "SHOW TABLES FROM $dbname";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

if (!$result) {
   echo 'Error MySQL : ' . mysql_error();
}

Comment: Yes, using Hostgator and then going into PHPmyadmin (no login required) I can see my database name and I can see my table called "company" and in that table there are thousands of rows which I can run queries against. This is really strange.

Comment: Did you try to execute the line i gave you ? 
If php can't display all tables from your database, i think your pwd is wrong.
Btw, did you try to use 'root' as login and nothing as password like :$username = "root" OR "admin"; 
$password = "";

Comment: When trying admin or root and no password I get: Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: Access denied for user 'admin'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in /home3/ste19841/public_html/index.php on line 75
 Unable to connect to MySQL

Comment: Also, when I run that line of code to show all tables I get nothing. I don't get any additional error, I just see the same on my page as I did without the show tables code.

Comment: Man, I think I have got it. :( You were right, I apologies relentlessly. The password I was using was the PHPmyadmin users password that I created against that database. It wanted my Hostgator login password!! Unbelievable. Thank you all so much for the help and I can only sorry it was not something more exciting!

Comment: If you have nothing on your page when your addind my line, it's because php detect 0 tables on your database.
Look identical error : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2343647/access-denied-for-user-speedycm-rootlocalhost-to-database-speedycms

I don't have more ideas sorry

Comment: nomally : Use the green checkbox on the left if the answer is acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

THe most likely cause is that the database "my_dbname" doesn't exist. Also, use mysqli or PDO. mysql is deprecated and insecure.

Comment: The database name is not actually "my_dbname" it is something else which I don't want to post up.

Comment: OK, but make sure it's the same as what you have in your script. Anyway, I don't think this is the problem, based on your other comment.